Ubuntu after upgrade to 24.04 does not use gpu
After upgrading to ubuntu 24.04 from 23.10 suddenly the gpu stopped working. Browser, KDE plasma, steam games use software acceleration. What's more, KDE plasma on wayland has stopped working and after logging off (I use SDDM) I only see a black screen. HDMI and sound output work as expected. No solution found on the internet helps. I really want to avoid reinstalling the system if possible. Please help

lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' output:

`03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile
 Series] (rev c2)
         Subsystem: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
         Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
         Kernel modules: amdgpu


sudo dmesg | grep -i amd output:

[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=UUID=383f6598-9b04-409b-b94f-fc8eb1d2cd5b ro quiet splash radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.024902] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=UUID=383f6598-9b04-409b-b94f-fc8eb1d2cd5b ro quiet splash radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.241195] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (family: 0x17, model: 0x18, stepping: 0x1)
gabriel@gabriel-NBLK-WAX9X:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i amd
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.5.0-28-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-001) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41) #29-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Mar 28 23:46:48 UTC 2024 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-28.29-generic 6.5.13)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=UUID=383f6598-9b04-409b-b94f-fc8eb1d2cd5b ro quiet splash radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.006034] RAMDISK: [mem 0x817d0000-0x85d76fff]
[    0.024902] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=UUID=383f6598-9b04-409b-b94f-fc8eb1d2cd5b ro quiet splash radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.075997] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:PNP0D40, uid:, rdevid:152
[    0.075999] AMD-Vi: Using global IVHD EFR:0x4f77ef22294ada, EFR2:0x0
[    0.094976] AMD Zen1 DIV0 bug detected. Disable SMT for full protection.
[    0.241195] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (family: 0x17, model: 0x18, stepping: 0x1)
[    0.241462] Performance Events: Fam17h+ core perfctr, AMD PMU driver.
[    0.444448] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[    0.447723] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Found IOMMU cap 0x40
[    0.447727] AMD-Vi: Extended features (0x4f77ef22294ada, 0x0): PPR NX GT IA GA PC GA_vAPIC
[    0.447743] AMD-Vi: Interrupt remapping enabled
[    0.447770] AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
[    0.448187] perf/amd_iommu: Detected AMD IOMMU #0 (2 banks, 4 counters/bank).
[    0.500931] amd_pstate: the _CPC object is not present in SBIOS or ACPI disabled
[    1.143926] input: ELAN2204:00 04F3:3109 Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2204:00/0018:04F3:3109.0001/input/input5
[    1.144113] input: ELAN2204:00 04F3:3109 Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2204:00/0018:04F3:3109.0001/input/input7
[    1.298811] input: ELAN2204:00 04F3:3109 Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2204:00/0018:04F3:3109.0001/input/input8
[    1.298955] input: ELAN2204:00 04F3:3109 Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2204:00/0018:04F3:3109.0001/input/input10
[    4.511761] kvm_amd: TSC scaling supported
[    4.511768] kvm_amd: Nested Virtualization enabled
[    4.511772] kvm_amd: Nested Paging enabled
[    4.511776] kvm_amd: SEV enabled (ASIDs 0 - 15)
[    4.511780] kvm_amd: SEV-ES enabled (ASIDs 0 - 4294967295)
[    4.511806] kvm_amd: Virtual VMLOAD VMSAVE supported
[    4.511809] kvm_amd: Virtual GIF supported
[    4.511811] kvm_amd: LBR virtualization supported
[    4.870465] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 loaded and initialized
[    7.793771] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    7.812071] amdgpu: CRAT table disabled by module option
[    7.812076] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[    7.812095] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[    7.821027] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
[    7.821033] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-PICASSO-115
[    7.827633] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    7.827638] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature enabled
[    7.827697] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 1024M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F43FFFFFFF (1024M used)
[    7.827701] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF
[    7.827703] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: AGP: 267419648M 0x000000F800000000 - 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF
[    7.827871] [drm] amdgpu: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[    7.827874] [drm] amdgpu: 3428M of GTT memory ready.
[    7.828502] amdgpu: hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is smu10_smu
[    7.829847] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    7.956449] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
[    7.975370] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
[    7.986136] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Secure display: Generic Failure.
[    7.986146] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: query securedisplay TA failed. ret 0x0
[    7.996469] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[    8.133139] amdgpu: HMM registered 1024MB device memory
[    8.136828] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
[    8.136854] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Total number of KFD nodes to be created: 1
[    8.137029] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for GPU
[    8.137232] amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x15d8:0x1002]
[    8.137239] kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:15d8
[    8.137264] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SE 1, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 11, active_cu_number 8
[    8.137535] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[    8.137542] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_low uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[    8.137548] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_high uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[    8.137554] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[    8.137560] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[    8.137566] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[    8.137571] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[    8.137577] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[    8.137583] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[    8.137589] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[    8.137595] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[    8.137601] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_0.2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[    8.137607] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 8
[    8.137613] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 8
[    8.137618] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 8
[    8.137624] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 8
[    8.137629] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 8
[    8.146965] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.54.0 20150101 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 0
[    8.155425] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    8.155443] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device


You are using several apps that may not work with 24.04 until whom ever makes them updates them.

I'm not sure if this might be the same problem here as I had, but I had similar problems using my Dedicated GPU (7800XT - Navi 31) to play games using Steam on 24.04. My solution was to deactivate the iGPU at the Bios, solved all my issues at once.
sudo dmesg | grep -i amd
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.8.0-31-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-080) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 (Ubuntu 6.8.0-31.31-generic 6.8.1)
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.003073] RAMDISK: [mem 0x523ad000-0x56942fff]
[    0.003360] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000074A33000 007F64 (v02 AMD    Splinter 00000002 MSFT 04000000)
[    0.003368] ACPI: VFCT 0x00000000749FD000 00E284 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000001 AMD  33504F47)
[    0.003372] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000748BF000 009BAE (v02 AMD    AMD CPU  00000001 AMD  00000001)
[    0.003373] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000074A2D000 0008BA (v02 AMD    CPMDFDG2 00000001 INTL 20230331)
[    0.003374] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000074A2C000 000788 (v02 AMD    CPMDFIG5 00000001 INTL 20230331)
[    0.003375] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000748B5000 009A57 (v02 AMD    CPMCMN   00000001 INTL 20230331)
[    0.003377] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000074A29000 00240A (v02 AMD    AOD      00000001 INTL 20230331)
[    0.003380] ACPI: IVRS 0x0000000074A26000 0000C8 (v02 AMD    AmdTable 00000001 AMD  00000001)
[    0.003381] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000074A25000 000500 (v02 AMD    MEMTOOL0 00000002 INTL 20230331)
[    0.003382] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000748B4000 0009E6 (v02 AMD    CPMMSOSC 00000001 INTL 20230331)
[    0.003384] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000748B3000 00047C (v02 AMD    AMDWOV   00000001 INTL 20230331)
[    0.003385] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000748B2000 00044E (v02 AMD    AmdTable 00000001 INTL 20230331)
[    0.003386] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000748B1000 000771 (v02 AMD    AmdTable 00000001 INTL 20230331)
[    0.235108] AMD-Vi: Using global IVHD EFR:0x246577efa2254afa, EFR2:0x0
[    0.365802] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X 16-Core Processor (family: 0x19, model: 0x61, stepping: 0x2)
[    0.365947] Performance Events: Fam17h+ 16-deep LBR, core perfctr, AMD PMU driver.
[    0.488319] pci 0000:00:02.1: bridge window [mem 0xf5a00000-0xf66fffff]: can't claim; address conflict with AMDIF031:00 [mem 0xf5c00000-0xf5c00fff]
[    0.511210] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[    0.514612] AMD-Vi: Extended features (0x246577efa2254afa, 0x0): PPR NX GT [5] IA GA PC GA_vAPIC
[    0.514618] AMD-Vi: Interrupt remapping enabled
[    0.747638] AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
[    0.747893] perf: AMD IBS detected (0x00000bff)
[    0.747901] perf/amd_iommu: Detected AMD IOMMU #0 (2 banks, 4 counters/bank).
[   21.260761] kvm_amd: TSC scaling supported
[   21.260764] kvm_amd: Nested Virtualization enabled
[   21.260766] kvm_amd: Nested Paging enabled
[   21.260779] kvm_amd: Virtual VMLOAD VMSAVE supported
[   21.260780] kvm_amd: Virtual GIF supported
[   21.260780] kvm_amd: Virtual NMI enabled
[   21.260781] kvm_amd: LBR virtualization supported
[   22.434777] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[   22.434910] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[   22.434922] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[   22.435033] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[   22.440149] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
[   22.440152] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-EXT90249-100
[   22.446296] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: CP RS64 enable
[   22.450612] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:jpeg_v4_0_early_init [amdgpu]] JPEG decode is enabled in VM mode
[   22.472499] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   22.472506] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature not supported
[   22.472544] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: MEM ECC is not presented.
[   22.472545] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SRAM ECC is not presented.
[   22.472595] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 16368M 0x0000008000000000 - 0x00000083FEFFFFFF (16368M used)
[   22.472597] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 512M 0x00007FFF00000000 - 0x00007FFF1FFFFFFF
[   22.472717] [drm] amdgpu: 16368M of VRAM memory ready
[   22.472719] [drm] amdgpu: 64257M of GTT memory ready.
[   22.473512] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[   22.792715] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
[   22.792718] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
[   22.792746] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: smu driver if version = 0x0000003d, smu fw if version = 0x00000040, smu fw program = 0, smu fw version = 0x00504a00 (80.74.0)
[   22.792749] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU driver if version not matched
[   22.878987] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is initialized successfully!
[   22.913531] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[   23.292382] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:jpeg_v4_0_hw_init [amdgpu]] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
[   23.349255] amdgpu: HMM registered 16368MB device memory
[   23.350527] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
[   23.350542] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Total number of KFD nodes to be created: 1
[   23.350584] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for GPU
[   23.350742] amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x747e:0x1002]
[   23.350744] kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:747e
[   23.350757] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SE 3, SH per SE 2, CU per SH 10, active_cu_number 60
[   23.350761] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_0.0.0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[   23.350763] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[   23.350764] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[   23.350765] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[   23.350766] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[   23.350767] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[   23.350768] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[   23.350769] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[   23.350770] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[   23.350771] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[   23.350773] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma1 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[   23.350773] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_unified_0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 8
[   23.350775] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_unified_1 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 8
[   23.350776] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 8
[   23.350777] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring mes_kiq_3.1.0 uses VM inv eng 14 on hub 0
[   23.351752] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Using BACO for runtime pm
[   23.352357] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.57.0 20150101 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 1
[   23.364238] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   23.364241] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device

And no, I dont have any additional AMD drivers installed ...
